# How to force all URLs to have a trailing slash in Shopify

Tags: shopify, redirect, trailing-slash

By default Shopify ends urls without a trailing slash, though a path to a version with the trailing slash can still be used. I'd like to avoid having both url paths as options and force the version without a trailing slash to redirect to the version with the trailing slash.

Example: /collections/all would redirect to /collections/all/

I can do this manually, but I'd much rather prefer to have this done automatically.

What is the best way to handle this in Shopify?

Comment: I do not think there is a reason to worry about this. Nothing you do with Shopify can be impacted by this trailing slash issue. You are making an issue up here? Why do you want a trailing slash from a platform that does not issue one? Where is there a need for a trailing slash in anything you do with Shopify?

Comment: I'm in agreement with you and it certainly feels like an issue being created that doesn't need to be. However, it's part of the project requirements I have and I'm getting kick back from the client. If the solution is that I just have to tell the client "sorry, not going to happen" then I can push for that, but if there is a solution I'd prefer to satisfy the client and move on.

Comment: Ask for a justification. Seems to me they are asking for something misguided, perhaps due to their experience with older more primitive web platforms. As I said, there is zero need for trailing slash on a resource, so why bother. Waste of effort.

Comment: Sounds good. I feel I've done my due diligence and can at least show them I looked into it if that's ever needed.

Comment: @jhawes did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same need - I am moving a site from WP/Woo to Shopify - all of their currently indexed URLs contain a "/" at the end - rather than do a 301 redirect for them all (thousands) it would make more sense to enforce an appending trailing slash globally in Shopify (I know this is easily done via htaccess). This isn't a made up issue by any means - for efficiency and SEO impact it would make sense if there were a global setting of some sort for sites that were previously indexed this way.